# Why does implied volatility increase when we lower the risk-free interest rate?

Tags: implied-volatility

I don't understand it, when I calculate it I see it, but I can't explain it. Plus, $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}$ is positive so, could you explain me please ?
Is it because the market is more volatile when the price is decreasing ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "delta C by delta IV"? Is it merely the vega of your option? If yes, it is supposed to be positive for a vanilla option : the more uncertainty (i.e. volatility), the more valuable your right to choose, i.e. the option.

Comment: Yes, that's right, sorry I should've use latex for it. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lower the risk-free rate, the NPV of the strike that you will pay at maturity is higher, thus reducing the PV of your payoff and so the price of your option.

Yet, your option price is fixed: it is the market price of your option, from which you want to imply the Black-Scholes volatility. Your lower risk-free rate is supposed to lower the price, so it will have to "get higher" through the only free parameter of the formula, i.e. the implied volatility.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has become crystal clear.